# How can I detect changed fields inside a dataset?

Tags: delphi

I have a TDataSet and want to detect every change on any field.

How can I

- detect which field has been changed (during a database update)?
- see in which way the data has been altered (value before => value after change)?

There are different events which would be possible to use

- BeforePost
- AfterPost
- OnUpdateRecord

`BeforePost` and `AfterPost` have "only" the new TDataSet. But where are the old values?

`OnUpdateRecord` has the following parameters: `ASender: TDataSet; ARequest: TFDUpdateRequest; var AAction: TFDErrorAction; AOptions: TFDUpdateRowOptions`

I cannot see how to get the changed data.

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure cdsTableBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  z: integer;
  sFieldName: string;
  sOldValue, sNewValue: variant;
begin
  inherited;
  for z := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do begin // Interate through all datafields
    if DataSet.Fields[z].OldValue <> DataSEt.Fields[z].NewValue then begin // Only look at fields with changed data
      sFieldName := DataSet.Fields[z].FieldName;
      sOldValue := DataSet.Fields[z].OldValue;
      sNewValue := DataSet.Fields[z].NewValue;
      // ... do something with the retrieved information ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: EVariantConversionError: "Cannot convert Null to a string"

Comment: @dummzeuch yes, sOldValue and sNewValue should be declared as Variant, not String.

Comment: I have changed the declaration to variant. (In my case it worked with string because the fields are strings and integers.)

Comment: Use the method `VarSameValue` from the unit `System.variants` instead of the unequal operator `<>` for the comparison of `variant`.

Comment: @USauter Why should I do that? What is the problem if I use `<>`?